# SpecFlow with xUnit Net Core 2.0 Test Project

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017, specflow, xunit

Is it possible to run SpecFlow with xUnit and Net Core 2.0 Test Projects in Visual Studio 2017 yet?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for .NET Core 2.0 yet in SpecFlow.

See the current status here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/projects/2

Answer (score 0):

I've run XunitTestProject with specflow. you would need to install specflow 2.2.1,  specflow.netcore (1.2.0) and specflow.xunit(2.2.1) to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes SpecFlow 3 supports .NET Core [SpecFlow 3](https://specflow.org/2019/specflow-3-is-here/)